# getLoadedProductCollection() on boolean module Google Tag Manager

Tags: magento2, product

When I open a product page, i see the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getLoadedProductCollection() on boolean in /vendor/magento/module-google-tag-manager/Block/ListJson.php:204 Stack trace: 
#0 /vendor/magento/module-google-tag-manager/Block/ListJson.php(188): Magento\GoogleTagManager\Block\ListJson->_getProductCollection() 
#1 /vendor/magento/module-google-tag-manager/Block/ListJson.php(238): Magento\GoogleTagManager\Block\ListJson->_getProducts() 
#2 /vendor/magento/module-google-tag-manager/view/frontend/templates/impression.phtml(11): Magento\GoogleTagManager\Block\ListJson->getLoadedProductCollection()

#3 /home/mariana.nassar/var/www/enterprise-dutyfree/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/...') 
#4 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(255) in /vendor/magento/module-google-tag-manager/Block/ListJson.php on line 204
```

I don't know why, but I think was something with the category of product? All the product have the same error.

Comment: I have the same problem ... Can anyone help us?

Answer (score 2):

It's a native issue, in order to solve that issue you can do one of these options:

- Disable the Google Tag Manager
- Remove the block **related_products_impression**
- Install a third-party module to do that (Or create a new one based on that).
  https://marketplace.magento.com/chapagain-googletagmanager2.html

Answer (score 0):

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getLoadedProductCollection() 
on boolean in /vendor/magento/module-google-tag-manager/Block/ListJson.php: ...
```

This issue come, if we removed any one of these block(s) `catalog.product.related` or `product.info.upsell` or `checkout.cart.crosssell` or `search_result_list` or `checkout.cart.crosssell` or `category.products.list`.

**Solution :** To make it work use this created [patch](https://github.com/kanhaiya5590/Fatal-error-with-Google-Tag-Manager-in-Magento-2.3.x/blob/master/kanhaiya5590-google-tag-manager-issue-if-no-list-block-found.patch) and same kind of issue posted on [github](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/20164) for reference.

if some reason [patch](https://github.com/kanhaiya5590/Fatal-error-with-Google-Tag-Manager-in-Magento-2.3.x/blob/master/kanhaiya5590-google-tag-manager-issue-if-no-list-block-found.patch) not working, then create **preference** of `vendor/magento/module-google-tag-manager/Block/ListJson.php` and override the function `_getProductCollection()`

```
protected function _getProductCollection()
{
      if(!$this->getListBlock()) { // To check list block exist or not if not then return null
            return null;
      } else {
            return parent::_getProductCollection();
      }
}
```

Top of this any help required, that will be more appreciated.

**Note:** The above shared code tested on **Magento v2.3.3**