# How to remove up sell product from the cart page

Tags: magento2.2.4

How to remove up sell and cross sell product from the cart page. (you may also like block) I added below code in my `app/design/frontend/Custom/Theme/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml` file but when I click view cart page I am getting 500 error.

```
<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.upsell" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.crosssell" remove="true"/>
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is **no** `Upsells` in cart but `Crosssells` instead.

**Up-Sell :** offered to the customer as a pricier or higher-quality alternative to the product the customer is **looking at**.

**Cross-Sell :** "impulse-buy" products appear next to the **shopping cart** as cross-sells to the items already in the shopping cart.

To remove that crosssells from cart :

> app/design/frontend/Custom/Theme/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.crosssell" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Don't forget to clean a cache : `php bin/magento cache:clean`

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I have one more question how to remove  Upsells from product details page. i added below code in the 
  
 app/design/frontend/Tristar/custom/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml  and not working                                                                                                                             <referenceBlock name="product.info.upsell" remove="true"/>

Comment: The code looks good, run this : `php bin/magento cache:clean`, `php bin/magento cache:flush`, `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

Comment: After i make this change i am getting 500 error

Comment: Looks like this issue is related to Google Tag Manager Module comes with Magento. based on this post https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/212572/getloadedproductcollection-on-boolean-module-google-tag-manager I disable the GTM then the page working as expected.